# emulator crashes

Tags: android-emulator

I am setting up an Android environment for the first time on Eclipse. I have many years of Eclipse experience, but new to Android. This is being done on an Apple Mac Mini, running MacOSX 10.6.3. I am using the latest Eclipse Classic, version 3.5.2. I am trying to get the tiny hello world program running.

When I run it, I get the following in the console window of Eclipse:

[2010-06-12 13:48:08 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Android2.2AVD'
[2010-06-12 13:48:08 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Android2.2AVD'
[2010-06-12 13:48:11 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2010-06-12 13:48:11 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2010-06-12 13:48:12 - Emulator] 2010-06-12 13:48:12.783 emulator[50495:903] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
[2010-06-12 13:48:19 - HelloAndroid] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch'!

The emulator crashes with the following info.
I have followed all the instructions for running the hello world sample.
Anyone have any ideas?

Process:         emulator [50398]
Path:            /Users/jeremy/android-sdk-mac_86/tools/emulator
Identifier:      emulator
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  eclipse [50388]

Date/Time:       2010-06-12 13:28:38.595 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.3 (10D573)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          363037 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           9
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   7

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000007fd000
Crashed Thread:  4

Thread 0:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   emulator                        0x000eed4e helper_set_cp15 + 30

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9020bbd2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9020c168 _pthread_wqthread + 941
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9020bd86 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9020cb42 kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9020d25c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 215
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9020c719 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 163
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9020c4be _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 240
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9020bf41 _pthread_wqthread + 390
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9020bd86 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x901e635a semaphore_timedwait_signal_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90213ea1 _pthread_cond_wait + 1066
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90242a28 pthread_cond_timedwait_relative_np + 47
3   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x9056f965 CAGuard::WaitFor(unsigned long long) + 219
4   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x90572997 CAGuard::WaitUntil(unsigned long long) + 289
5   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x90570294 HP_IOThread::WorkLoop() + 1892
6   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x9056fb2b HP_IOThread::ThreadEntry(HP_IOThread*) + 17
7   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x9056fa42 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 140
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x90213a19 _pthread_start + 345
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x9021389e thread_start + 34

Thread 4 Crashed:
0   emulator                        0x00040380 audioInDeviceIOProc + 96

Thread 4 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0x007fd000  ecx: 0x000001fe  edx: 0x0198f3f0
  edi: 0x00000200  esi: 0x01119850  ebp: 0x01119800  esp: 0xb020fad0
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010212  eip: 0x00040380   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x0000001f   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0x007fd000

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same problem just now, and when I googled around a bit, I found some threads where people mentioned using Logitech USB headsets, and that unplugging those headsets made the problem go away.
I have a Logitech USB desktop microphone, and sure enough, after unplugging it, the problem went away for me, too. Even though the mic was turned off the whole time!

Comment: Same problem for me...I found, as per http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=887 that you don't have to remove the USB audio device--you just have to set the default audio input and output to the internal audio.  It is annoying that this bug has been there since 2008 and has not been fixed.

Comment: Similar problem for me, but with an Onkyo receiver plugged in.  When I unplugged it, the emulator starts up fine.  Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Having connected the Apple LED Cinema Display, just setting audio input to internal solved the problem for me - no need to set external audio playback aside.